# how object slicing happens in c++?

Tags: c++, inheritance

both the lines 1 and 2 will do object slicing or line one alone? thanks for your time !

```
class Base{
};

class Derived : public Base{
};

main()
{       
   Derived d1;
   Base b1 = d1;  //line 1
   Base &b2 = d1; // line 2
}
```

Comment: You forgot a return type for `main`.

Comment: hey David Heffernan, thank you for your input!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only the first assignment can lead to slicing, since that assignment involves a copy. The second assignment merely takes a reference to the object. Without a copy, there can be no slicing.